# How to use AzureDevOps predefined variables in Bash/Powershell scripts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In an AzureDevOps pipeline, I have tasks written in Bash/Powershell script.
If I choose to use **Inline** scrpit, I can use predefined variables directly, such as

```
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

However, if I choose to use a file path to call a script, I can't use predefined variable directly in the script file.  I have to pass the predefined variable to an environment variable in the task definition, like in the example below, so I can use $SourceDirectoy in script.sh,
[image]

Is there a better way to call predefined variable direclty in the script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the variables are also made available to scripts, but the formatting to reference them in the script might depend on script type.  Reference the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline).

> Notice that variables are also made available to scripts through
> environment variables. The syntax for using these environment
> variables depends on the scripting language.
>
> The name is upper-cased, and the . is replaced with the _. This is
> automatically inserted into the process environment. Here are some
> examples:
>
> - Batch script: %VARIABLE_NAME%
> - PowerShell script: $env:VARIABLE_NAME
> - Bash script: $VARIABLE_NAME

> Predefined variables that contain file paths are translated to the
> appropriate styling (Windows style C:\foo\ versus Unix style /foo/)
> based on agent host type and shell type. If you are running bash
> script tasks on Windows, you should use the environment variable
> method for accessing these variables rather than the pipeline variable
> method to ensure you have the correct file path styling.

Comment: I just tried running a bash script on a Windows build agent, but this still get's me a Windows-style path: `echo "${BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY}"` - exactly the same as `echo "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"` does